how to darken everything behind a modal component in expo
i am creating a mobile app using expo and i created a modal component but i have no idea of how to make the screen behind it entire black.
Modal
function MyModal({ handleClose, children, ...props }: ModalProps) {
  return (
    <Modal onRequestClose={handleClose} {...props}>
      <Styles.Container>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleClose}>
          <Styles.ModalOverlay tint="dark" intensity={60} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

        {children}
      </Styles.Container>
    </Modal>
  );
}

Styles (i am using styled components)
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';
import { transparentize } from 'polished';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export const Container = styled.View`
  height: ${Dimensions.get('window').height}px;
  width: ${Dimensions.get('window').width}px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center; /* can also use 'flex-end' for bottomsheet style */
  align-items: center;
`;

export const ModalOverlay = styled(BlurView)`
  height: ${Dimensions.get('window').height}px;
  width: ${Dimensions.get('window').width}px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) =>
    transparentize(0.7, theme.COLORS.MAIN_100)};
`;


App screen shoot
as you can see the statusbar and the device's bottom buttons are not dark

